# Positioning images with CSS

Tags: css, image

I have this code :

```
<div id="container"> 
<div id="header"> logo ... 
<div id"main"> some content....
```

The container width is 960px.
So... I want to put after the main section a large image(2000x300px)
how I can do this ?

Comment: That seems like a huge image...anyways, do you mind posting some of your current code?

Comment: Your question couldn't be more vague.

Comment: @Trip: "I want to put an image on an element after a section which is some width. How can I do this?" :P

Comment: @Drackir If only I had two upvotes to give

Comment: @alex 1. take the image 2. go to the DIV 3. find the main section 4. put the image after that main section

Comment: I've edited my post , now I'm more specific

Comment: @alexandru: This image is obviously much wider than every common screen resolution (except 2560x1200, which is not exactly "common"). What should the image look like? Should the user be able to scroll horizontally to see the rest of it? Should it be shrunk to `960px` width?

Comment: is not working with overflow:scroll

Comment: @thirtydot i want the user to scroll horizontally to see the  rest of it

Answer (score 2):

From your comment:

> @thirtydot i want the user to scroll
>   horizontally to see the rest of it

I understand what you want now.

You can do this:

```
<div id="largeImageContainer">
    <img .. />
</div>
```

with this **CSS**:

```
#largeImageContainer {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: scroll
}
```

Here's a [***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/QpYZh/) showing the idea. You should copy the code from this answer, not my demo.

About `overflow-x`; see: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Overflow-x

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">    
<html>
<head>    
    <style type="text/css">
        #mainSection{
            with:960px;
            background-image:url(http://mydomain.com/images/bg.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
    </style>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainSection"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also specify where you want to image to be, by adding something like this to the mainSection style definition:

```
    background-position:left top;
```